# mv files with certain extension

Tags: cygwin, move

I'm using cygwin on my PC and I'm looking to move all .nef files in /pictures/ (and sub directories) into a new directory, BUT I want to keep the directory name that the nef files came from.

ie /pictures/vacation2012/image01.nef
and
/pictures/vac09/image01.nef

should go into

/pictures/nef/vac09/
and
/pictures/nef/vacation2012/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$ cd from_directory
$ (tar cf - `find . -name "*.nef"`) | (cd to_directory; tar xf - )
$ find . -name "*.nef" -exec rm -rf {} \; # be careful with this...
```